# prepend with jquery 'feedback messages'

Tags: jquery, prepend

1. I want to display 5 user feedback messages in a span with the id 'messagefield'.
2. I want the spans to be stacked on top of each other with the newest on top
3. When 5 spans have stacked up, I want to remove them --> replace them
   with the following next 5 messages.

I want this endresult in the markup :

```
<div class="span4 messageField">
<span id="messagefield">Message 1</span>'
<span id="messagefield">Message 2</span>'
<span id="messagefield">Message 3</span>'
<span id="messagefield">Message 4</span>'
<span id="messagefield">Message 5</span>'
</div>
```

I have appended the first span messagefield to my div like this with jquery:

```
$('.messageField').prepend('<span id="messagefield"></span>');
```

Here is the click function that generates the text for the messagefield:

```
$("#fireCreate").click(function(e) {
        $("#messagefield").html("Importerar titelsida, vänta ...");
});
```

this is the markup in the html:

```
<div class="span4 messageField">
<!-- HERE IS WHERE THE SPANS WILL STACK UP -->
</div>
```

Comment: And the question you have is...?

Comment: There should not exist multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: id is meant to be unique and scripts targeting non-unique ids may not behave as you expect.  This may be a good place to use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
//the counter is here just to show you that this works, you could use this to generate an id
var counter = 0;
$("#fireCreate").click(function(e) {
    counter++;
    if($('.messageField span').length === 5){
        $('.messageField span:last').remove();
    }
    $('.messageField').prepend($('<span />', { id: "message"+counter, class: "singleMessage", text : "Importerar titelsida, vänta ..."+counter}));
});
```

look here http://jsfiddle.net/D4FQd/